# Covariates in Path model

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I am building  a path model which links different psychological constructs. This is the replication of a model I have previously tested in another sample.

The model fits the data well. When however I try to add an additional variable as covariate on the DV (i.e., a variable with an arrow pointed to the DV) the model does not fit the data  anymore (all indices decrease, chi-squared becomes significant).

What does that mean conceptually? Is the model wrong, because adding the covariates make it not fitting anymore? Or I can justify not using this covariate just because once added the model does not fit the data anymore?

Using simple multiple regression, my focal IV remains significant also after adding the covariate (which also remains significant).

I am aware this is a very easy question - but I am new to statistics and these approaches!

thank you for your answers!

Additional Information:

[image: This is the path diagram]

T2R and T2N predict T2m which in turn predict T2c and T2C (the mediators), which in turn predict T2P. T2S is the covariate. When the covariate is added to the model, the model does not fit the data anymore

Comment: Can you post your path diagram?

Comment: Thanks @StasK: I have added the model now below with a description.

Comment: This is a recursive/lower diagonal model (read about simultaneous equation models; it is surprisingly poorly understood by SEM modelers, and Bollen 1989 may be the only book that covers them well), and OLS estimates of it are unbiased (although better estimates can be constructed that are efficient). Going full SEM is an overkill, as you attempt to model absolutely irrelevant things such as the distribution of `T2R`, `T2N` and `T2S`. If you lose model fit by adding `T2S`, it may be correlated with some of the measurement errors. Model-implied instrumental variables estimation is another option